# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.18:redeploy (default-cli) on project

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am running and deploying on Windows. The app server is Tomcat 8.  Not clear what this error means or how to resolve it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

your question is similar my problem, I solved it. perhaps you have not properly started your server before using maven. for more details take a look at Deploying the JavaEE 8 Tutorial, by maven gets Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.6.4:redeploy (deploy) on project hello1

Comment: try to highlight the keywords and be clear with the format it will help to reach out your answer for others Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)